# Loop for resending smtp email on failure to send

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have a service that sends an email after a user registers. Every once in a while, a user contacts support with the complaint that they aren't receiving the email, so I've made a list of possible issues, one of which is a smtp failure to send email, which I noticed occasionally when I would step through the code. I want to write a simple loop that tries to resend the email a couple of times on failure to send, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I'd appreciate any advice on the subject.

```
public void MusicDownloadEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            const string mailBody = "Body text";
            mail.To.Add(email);
            mail.Subject = "Mail subject";
            mail.Body = mailBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            var exception = ex.Message.ToString();
            //Other code for saving exception message to a log.
        }
    }
```

Comment: So are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a 'failure to send email' error on a rare occasion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public void MusicDownloadEmail(string email)
{
    int tryAgain = 10;
    bool failed = false;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            failed = false;

            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            const string mailBody = "Body text";
            mail.To.Add(email);
            mail.Subject = "Mail subject";
            mail.Body = mailBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // I would avoid catching all exceptions equally, but ymmv
        {                
            failed = true;
            tryAgain--;
            var exception = ex.Message.ToString();
            //Other code for saving exception message to a log.
        }
    }while(failed  && tryAgain !=0)
}
```

Comment: code can be modified to retry only `smtp.Send(mail);` statement.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it recusively

Firstly define the maximum amount of retries

```
public const int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;
```

Then call the method using the retry count

```
MusicDownloadEmail("code@mail.com", MAX_RETRY_COUNT);
```

And modify the method as follows

```
public static void MusicDownloadEmail(string email, int retryCountsLeft) {
        if (retryCountsLeft > 1) {
            try {
                var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                const string mailBody = "Body text";
                mail.To.Add(email);
                mail.Subject = "Mail subject";
                mail.Body = mailBody;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                var exception = ex.Message.ToString();
                //Other code for saving exception message to a log.

                MusicDownloadEmail(email, --retryCountsLeft);
            }
        }
    }
```